# QGL, opengl - all values of zaxis outside of 1;-1 get clipped

Tags: qt, opengl

All figures outside of z-axis: (1;-1) range get clipped. Here is some code:

```
void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{
    glDepthRange(-2,2);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  // Enables Depth Testing
       glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);     // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
       glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);  // Enables Smooth Color Shading
       glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

}

void MainWindow::paintGL(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();
 // glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 // glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
 // glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,0 , image.width(), image.height(),  0, 0, image.bits() );
//glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
//glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, 1.9);
  qglColor(Qt::black);
      glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

      glVertex3d(-0.1,0.1,1);
      glVertex3d(-0.1,-0.1,-1);
      glVertex3d(0.1,-0.1,0);

      glEnd();

}
```

Any idea why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

#### This is actually completely normal behavior.

When you use identity modelview and projection matrices, your coordinates are in clip-space. The default `W` value for a 3D vertex in OpenGL is **1.0** (vertices are always 4D), and clip-space -> NDC works by dividing each component of a vertex by its `W` component and then clipping anything with a coordinate outside the range [-1,1].

I think what is confusing you is the `glDepthRange (...)` call. That does not affect clipping. Depth range is part of the viewport transformation, which happens ***after*** clipping.